# I'm using the li selector to drop and each li:hover will surround all underlying ul / lis

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, droppable

I have a simple nested ul / li list and I would like to highlight the underlying element while dropping.

The problem, I'm using the li selector to drop and each li:hover will surround all underlying ul / lis. Jquery-ui's droppable has an hover-class option for me, but I'm not seeing the trick how to apply it to my ul/lis.

html:

```
ul
- li
  a 
  ul
  - li
    a
  - li
    a
    ul
    - (...)
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable ul > li").draggable();
    $(".droppable > li").droppable({
        greedy: true,
        hoverClass: "drop-hover-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            // find the related element to append the dragged item
            $(this).find('> .list-inline').append('<li class="draggable">' + ui.draggable.html() + '</li>');
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

css

```
.drop-hover-highlight { background: #EEE }
```

I've thought about child / sibling selector but I'm not able to apply it to the 'hoverClass'?

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/qthm61ou/